# Save values between 'Steps' in Wizard ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net

I get this error in ASP.NET Wizard when I try to use values of TextBox control of previous step.

Error:

```
    The INSERT statement conflicted with the FOREIGN KEY constraint "FK_Contact_Emp". 
The conflict occurred in database "KKSTech", table "dbo.Emp", column 'EmpID'.
```

Is it a problem to access control's values of different steps?

Comment: This problem is coming due to incorrect Foreign Key value. Did you debug the code and get what textbox consist?

Comment: TextBox1 in Step1 is getting inserted into dbo.Emp (EmpID PK) but not inserted into dbo.contacts where that is a FK..

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to store values between steps in ASP.NET Wizard?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11690960/how-to-store-values-between-steps-in-asp-net-wizard)

Comment: @Girish be careful many delete questions can lead you to restrictions (like to not have permissions to make new questions)

Comment: @Aristos I have this same problem since weeks. So I had to open a new question. That was slightly different from this though. Plus my problems are solved yet..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A foreign key ensures that it cannot have a value in that column that is not also in the primary key column of the referenced table.

In your case , you are inserting `EmpID` into `contact` table which is not present in the referenced table of `EmpID` i.e `Emp` table.

Comment: EmpID is getting inserted into dbo.Emp table in which it is a PK.. I used separate class to insert Employees' details, but the same is not getting inserted into other table.

Comment: Have you checked whether TextBox1.Text in step1 have same value while inserting into the contacts table.....

Comment: No I haven't checked because in Wizard I learned that the values are not forgotten. How do I do that now? I am totally confused.. :(

Comment: Could you provide us db design of contact and Emp table so that we can have broad view about your problem....

Comment: Sure.. dbo.Emp (EmpID (PK), Fname, Lname, ......)
Dbo.Contacts(AddressID (PK), Adrline1, adrline2, CityID, EmpID(FK) );

Comment: I see nothing wrong with your table...so I still have some doubt on textbox value.....

Comment: Did you check the InsertInfo inserting the data into the database?

Comment: Yes.. That is fine.. Only problem is with columns with the FK attribute in other tables that I'm unable to insert those values..

Comment: I have executed all these info in the end like this
`protected void Wizard1_FinishButtonClick(object sender, WizardNavigationEventArgs e)
        {
            InsertInfo();
            Insertcert(); 
            Insertskills();
            Insertaddress();
            
        }`

Answer (score 1):

This is the First class that inserts into dbo.Emp table

```
 public void InsertInfo()
        {
            String KKStech = @"Data Source=USER-PC\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=KKSTech;Integrated Security=True";
            SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(KKStech);
            String insertstring = @"insert into Emp (EmpID, FirstName, LastName, MiddleName, Mob1, Mob2, Phone, Email1, Email2, EmpDesc)
                            values (@EmpID,  @FirstName, @LastName, @MiddleName, @Mob1, @Mob2)";
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(insertstring, conn);
            cmd.CommandText = insertstring;
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

            try
            {
                conn.Open();
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EmpID", TextBox1.Text);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@FirstName", TextBox2.Text);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@LastName", TextBox3.Text);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@MiddleName", TextBox4.Text);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Mob1", TextBox5.Text);
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Mob2", TextBox6.Text);
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }

            finally
            {
                conn.Close();
            }
        }
```

And this is the one where I 'm inserting into the table where EmpID is a FK

```
public void Insertaddress()
{
    String KKStech = @"Data Source=USER-PC\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=KKSTech;Integrated Security=True";
    SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(KKStech);
    String str = @"insert into Contact (Addressline1, Addressline2, CityID, EmpID)
                                values(@Addressline1, @Addressline2, @CityID, @EmpID)";
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(str, conn);
    cmd.CommandText = str;
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;

    try
    {
        conn.Open();
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Addressline1", TextBox15.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Addressline2", TextBox17.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CityID", DropDownList2.SelectedValue);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@EmpID", TextBox1.Text);
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
    catch (System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException ex)
    {
        string msg = "Insert Error:";
        msg += ex.Message;
        throw new Exception(msg);
    }

    finally
    {
        conn.Close();
    }

}
```

That was my problem.